# how to use id's from an arraylist to access columns on a database to generate new jsp table?

Tags: java, forms, jsp, servlets

I am working on an admin site where the user can view the list of employees displayed  from a database in a jsp form. The project uses java classes and servlets. In the form is the employees details as well as a check box with a value set to the employeeID (primary key in the database).

```
 <input type="checkbox" value="${employee.empID}" name="empArray">
```

Say I select 8 employee's I can pass their values back to the servlet and store them in an array list and print them. What I am struggling to achieve now is to use the empID's in the array list to access their matching  values in a database so I can create a table of the employees based on the id's stored in the array list.

In other words if   String[] empArray contains employee id's "5,7,9,20 ...etc" I want to be able to display their details in a new table so I can export the data for reports. Can anyone advise me on the best way to go about this?

below is the servlet code

```
                 String[] employeeArray ;

                employeeArray  = request.getParameterValues("empArray"); 
                 if (employeeArray != null && employeeArray.length != 0)  

             {
                 System.out.println("You have selected: ");
                  String empID="";
                   for (int i = 0; i < employeeArray.length; i++) 
             {
                 empID+=employeeArray[i]+"\n";
             }
              System.out.println(empID);
              session.setAttribute("employeeArray",  empID);

             }
```

Comment: What do you really need? You have the employees IDs, now just process them in order to get the employee details and add all the data as request attribute (or session, depending on your needs).

Answer (score 0):

Your code (formatted) is:

```
String[] employeeArray ;
employeeArray  = request.getParameterValues("empArray"); 

if (employeeArray != null && employeeArray.length != 0){
    System.out.println("You have selected: ");
    String empID="";

    for (int i = 0; i < employeeArray.length; i++) {
        empID+=employeeArray[i]+"\n";
    }

    System.out.println(empID);
    session.setAttribute("employeeArray",  empID);

}
```

The value you are adding to the session is not an array, it's a String

I have edited your code below. I've tried to use better names, and am assuming that you have a class to represent an Employee and a service to lookup database data.

```
...
EmployeeService service; // initialised else where
...

List<Employee> employees = new ArrayList<Employee>();
String[] employeeIds ;
employeeIds  = request.getParameterValues("empArray"); 

if (employeeIds != null && employeeIds.length != 0){
    String empID="";

    Employee employee;

    for (int i = 0; i < employeeIds.length; i++) {
        employee = service.find(employeeIds[i]); // get from database
        if(employee != null){
            employees.add(employee);
        }
    }

    session.setAttribute("employees",  employees);

}
```